# Error al enviar un dato vació a mysql desde java

Tags: java, mysql, date

Quiero  insertar unos datos a la `BD` pero la fecha en algunas ocasiones ira vacía, en la `BD` esta `null` pero si envió los datos del formulario me da el siguiente error

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date
>   value: '' for column 'fecha' at row 1

Cabe mencionar que estoy dejando el espacio de fecha en blanco

Comment: Tu columna admite el valor 'null' o algo del tipo 'Date', cuando en tu aplicación se deja el input de fecha en blanco deberias enviar a la base de datos el valor 'null' . Probablemente estas obteniendo el valor de fecha de tu formulario como un String y convirtiendolo a Date, por eso envias " a la base de datos.

Comment: Agrega tu Query por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que pasarle `null` explícitamente, no una cadena vacía, recuerda que `null!=''` y un campo de fecha no puede almacenar texto.

Para validar si la cadena está vacía puedes usar una condicional en linea:

```
String visita2 = request.getParameter("txtVisita");
visita2 = visita2 == "" ? null : visita2;
```

Sin embargo te recomiendo mejor pasar la fecha como `Date` al mysql, validando que lo que ingresa el usuario es correcto:

```
Date date = null;
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    date = sdf.parse(visita2);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: como lo haria? si el valor de la fecha lo mando en una variable a un metodo, es decir  String visita2 = request.getParameter("txtVisita"); visita 2 la mando en el metodo cn.getupdarticulo(visita2)

Comment: Igner, acabo de editar mi respuesta, para que veas como puedes hacer.

Comment: perdon estoy usando java lo solucione asi  String visita1 = request.getParameter("visita1");
                                            if (visita1 == "") {
                                                visita1 = null; me funciona bien pero gracias me ayudo lo de validar si era vacio mandarle un null

Comment: Hola Igmer, el código que compartí, también es java.

Comment: si eso vi ahora tengo el problema que los enteros no puedo enviarlos como nullo 
                             if (edadFracaso == "") {
                                Integer.parseInt(edadFracaso) = null; me da error al decirle que lo envie como null porque es entero

Comment: hola Igmer, marca la pregunta como solucionada y crea una nueva pregunta, no se puede preguntar en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

El error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date
> value: '' for column 'fecha' at row 1

**indica que el problema es que el valor de tipo `date` debe incluirse entre comillas simples (') antes de enviarlo a la base de datos.**